# Variadic Templates and Type Traits

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, variadic-templates

I currently have a variadic function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments of arbitrary types (duh), however, I want to restrict the types to ones which are POD only, and also the same size or smaller than that of a void*.

The void* check was easy, I just did this:

```
static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= sizeof(PVOID), "Size of types must be <= memsize.");
```

However I can't work out how to do the same for std::is_pod.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: `sizeof...(Args)` probably doesn't do what you intend - it returns how many arguments are in the argument pack (and not their sizes). See [this](http://ideone.com/X8X3p). If you want to limit their size, doing something like `static const bool value = sizeof(Head) <= sizeof(void*) && ...` would help, see [this](http://ideone.com/PUMXx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a meta-function to determine if all are POD types:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct all_pod;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct all_pod<Head, Tail...>
{
    static const bool value = std::is_pod<Head>::value && all_pod<Tail...>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct all_pod<T>
{
    static const bool value = std::is_pod<T>::value;
};
```

then

```
static_assert( all_pod<Args...>::value, "All types must be POD" );
```

Comment: Under GCC 4.6 this is giving me the following error (snipped to give the relevant parts): "type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list" "expected a type, got 'Args ...'"

Comment: Never mind, I'm a moron. I was passing the values not the types. Duh.

Comment: Doesn't work when `Args...` is empty. Better use: ```template<>
struct all_pod<>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};``` instead of ```template<typename T>
struct all_pod<T>
{
    static const bool value = std::is_pod<T>::value;
};```